# URL redirect when DNS is changed

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, dns

I have some DNS changes done.

```
test.com, test.nu, test.se, testme.com ----->welcome.se
```

All urls in the above servers must be redirected to http://welcome.se/abcd/test/index.html

I have written the following rewrite rules.

```
ReWriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(test|testme)\.(se|com|nu))$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://welcome.se/abcd/test/index.html [L,R=301]
```

Can someone tell me if this perfect.

I just tried this. I do not have any method to test it.

Comment: You just have an extra `)` so it should be: `ReWriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(test|testme)\.(se|com|nu)$ [NC]`

Comment: @anubhava. Thank you for the response. I am also redirecting all the requests in my server with pattern/abcd/* to another server.Would you also review it. 
   
  **RewriteRule   ^/abcd/(.+)  http://test.se/$1  [R,L]**

Comment: Ok let me post both rules in answer since posting code in comment is very difficult here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code:

```
RewriteEngine On

ReWriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(test|testme)\.(se|com|nu)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://welcome.se/abcd/test/index.html [L,R=301]

RewriteRule ^abcd/(.+)$ http://test.se/$1 [NC,R=301,L]
```

Comment: Can you tell me the significance of [NC,R=301,L]. and $

Comment: Yes sure. NC - Ignore Case match, R=301 - Redirect with HTTP status=301, L - Last rule. Where `$` in regex means end of input.

Comment: Thank you for the clear answer. Here in the above first rule, I am writing redirects in welcome.se. Is it really important to write teh complete path there or can we write RewriteRule ^ /abcd/test/index.html [L,R=301]. Could you please confirm.

Comment: Oh yes sure you can write: `RewriteRule ^ /abcd/test/index.html [L,R=301]` also.